# Bind .each() to dynamically added element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Is there a way to loop through dynamically elements added after page load? Something like this...

```
if ($('#myFlag').length < 2) {
    $(document).on('each', '.myEm', function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
}
```

If it was on `click` it'll work just fine, but not on `each`. To clarify, I am wanting to know *how* I can execute the above on a dynamically added element without chaining off the event that added that element in the first place. In other words, is there a generic event for which I can leverage when a DOM element is added?

Comment: The first argument to `.on()` has to be an event name. There's no `each` event, I'm not even sure what that would mean.

Comment: `each` is not an event so `.on('each')` doesn't make sense. Maybe you just want `$('.myEm').remove()`? (the `each` loop is implicit in this case).

Comment: If you want to use `.each`, the syntax is `$(".myEm").each(function()...)`

Comment: I tried .each() but some of the elements were added after page load and my script did not see them in DOM.

Comment: If your wanting to remove 'only' dynamically added elements, then you'll need some other identifier on the elements to tell that.  Otherwise the dom doesn't keep track of that.  Otherwise you could keep a reference to them in a javascript array or something, and remove the elements in that array.  But giving them a common class to identify them would be simplier.

Comment: When do you run this code? It needs to be in something that runs **after** you add the elements to the DOM.

Comment: Yes, that's why I am asking for a way to bind it...

Comment: There's something else that doesn't make sense: `if ($("#myFlag").length < 2)`. There can only be one element with `id="myFlag"`, so the length will always be < 2.

Comment: You could use `setInterval` to run your code periodically in the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just target and remove them? Observe the following example...

```
$('.myEm').remove()
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/shoao0m4/) - simplified demo

---

If you want to "listen" for these elements being added and perform this logic on that trigger, perhaps you can subscribe to the [DOMSubtreeModified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMSubtreeModified) or [DOMNodeInserted](http://help.dottoro.com/ljmcxjla.php) mutation event. Observe the following...

```
$(document).on('DOMSubtreeModified', function() { // or DOMNodeInserted
    $('.myEm').remove();
});
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/vm7a4hj7/) - DOM mutation event demo

---

[MutationObservers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) may possibly be leveraged here as well, and are preferred while also offering more control. An example of this may include the following...

```
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

var target = document.querySelector('body');

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {

        // check if added node has class myEm
        if($(mutation.addedNodes).hasClass('myEm')) {

            // -- timeout for visual demonstration
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(mutation.addedNodes).remove(); // .myEm
            }, 1000);
        }
    });    
});

observer.observe(target, config);
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/5b467q5L/) - mutation observer example

Comment: How widely implemented is `DOMSubtreeModified`? MDN doesn't have a compatibility table, it's not included in quirksmode.com's event compatibility page.

Comment: NM, found a table here: http://help.dottoro.com/ljfvvdnm.php#additionalEvents

Comment: Cool I was about to post the same reference. IE 9 and up? Sold! lol

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? This seems to work well

Comment: Asking for explanations of downvotes is a waste of time, they won't see the message. I gave you an upvote to make up for him.

Comment: There have been times when I did hear feedback if asked for it even when the vote started as anonymous. I wish feedback was given, however. I tried improving this even further

Comment: I suppose some voters check back to see if anything has improved. But meanwhile, your comment sends a notification to the last commenter (me, in this case).

Comment: ah sorry about that, I was not trying to ask you specifically but hoping it was checked back on. Thanks for the support in this case

Comment: I realize that. Just remember that when there's no `@name` in the comment, it defaults to notifying the most recent commenter (there's a little more logic to it, but that's the basics).